# I have a grass like flower plant. What is that

Tags: identification, houseplants

I have a grass like flower plant .which I bought from a gardener. What is this? [image][image] this plant have white flowers and need large amount of water

Comment: BTW, probably it is not grass (Graminae/Paceae), but rush (Juncaceae): no nodes. But the photos are very ugly (phones and camera tend not to be good on plants [and green things]). Put an hand or a newspaper just behind the stem, so that your phone will focus right (and not the background or soil). It the stem round (ev. compressed) or triangular? Are there nodes (make a picture). I'm also not excluding Equisetum, but it depends on what do you mean for "white flowers". Are they like grasses or like cotton?

Comment: 2nd image is clear ,it need sun light For 4 to 5 hours, it produce white flowers when it fully grow

Comment: There is this little ditty that helps; Grasses have KNEES, Sedges have EDGES and Rushes are ROUND.  This is indeed a rush.Not a grass.  How did you know that this plant can stand this kind of water and mud?  Probably not that great when the water and mud become very stinky, even marshes have fresh water replacing the stagnant.  This plant is a marsh or water's edge plant.  Not an aquatic plant like a water lily.  Where do you imagine planting it?  Do you have a water feature or a little pond?